# Error al crear un proyecto en Ionic 7: Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'

Tags: nodejs, angular, ionic, npm

Se creo el proyecto y se ejecuta ionic serve y aparece el error:

PS D:\app> ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
> [ng] Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
> [ng]   Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al ser un proyecto nuevo lo que hice fue: borrar el proyecto nuevo, desisntalar e instalar ionic, volver a crearlo y quedo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero que les sirva a otros. Si tienen una solución diferente me gustaría que lo compartan; adjunto imágenes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]